# Readin files with enconding OEM 850 in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, encoding

I have to read text files in Swift/Cocoa, which are encoded as OEM 850. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will see you have negative and close votes on your question. SO really expects people to show effort; e.g. report what they've read/tried, show code, describe errors, etc. New people are usually allowed some slack, but you should keep this in mind in any future questions. Hope that helps and I've added an answer to hopefully help you along with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can first read the file in as raw data and then convert that data to a string value according to your encoding. A small wrinkle in your case:

> There are two types which represent the known string encodings, [`NSStringEncoding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstringencoding) ([`String.Encoding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/encoding) in Swift) and [`CFStringEncoding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfstringencoding?language=objc). Apple only directly defines a subset of the known encodings as `NSStringEncoding`/`String.Encoding` values. The remaining known encodings have `CFStringEncoding` values and the function [`CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1543046-cfstringconvertencodingtonsstrin?language=occ) is provided to map these to `NSStringEncoding`. Unfortunately for you OEM 850 is only directly provided by `CFStringEncoding`...

That sounds worse than it is. In Objective-C you can get the encoding you require using:

```
NSStringEncoding dosLatin1 = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingDOSLatin1);
```

*Note: “DOS Latin 1” is one of the names for the same coding “OEM 850” refers to (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) for a list) and is the one Apple chose hence the `kCFStringEncodingDOSLatin1`.*

In Swift this is messier:

```
let dosLatin1 = String.Encoding(rawValue: CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(CFStringEncodings.dosLatin1.rawValue)))
```

Once you have the encoding the rest is straightforward, **without error checking** an outline is:

```
let sourceURL = ...
let rawData = try? Data(contentsOf: sourceURL)
let convertedString = String(data: rawData, encoding: dosLatin1)
```

In real code you **must** check that the file read and conversion are succesful. Reading raw data from a URL in Swift will throw if the read fails, converting the data to a string produces an optional (`String?`) as the conversion may fail.

HTH